# Why no true black background in dark themes?

Tags: editor

Editors and IDEs like Atom and Eclipse display white on gray, not white on black. As some who wants maximum contrast I find that unintuitive, as I can just reduce monitor brightness and increase ambient light if I want less. However in terminals like gnome-terminal, choosing white on black has actual black. What is the reason for this?

Comment: Uninformed designers whose total education comes from reading headlines on reddit.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an optician but as far as I know it comes down to how the eye is built and how it perceives the contrast. I.e. too much contrast, especially from bright spots causes that burned spots in your eyesight appear - try looking at the sun for a moment, for the next minute you will see a spot in your eyesight wherever you look.

It also concerns website design - even though a page with bright (white or light grey) background and dark text may seem shining right in your face, is much more pleasing to read than the one with the colours flipped.

As for the terminal colours I'd say the black background is historical. Even though I'm not in favour of such radical colour scheme (personally I chose dark grey with green or amber).

Bear in mind that in past times (CRT monitors) the darker the colour the less the usage of luminofor there was. Also, screen savers were not meant for energy saving but for allowing the screen to last longer with proper colours. From my experience (let's shift back to the 90's), we have been using [ChiWriter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChiWriter) for years and after switching to Windows 3.1 there were darker lines and spots burned on the monitor visible.

Funny fact is that an LCD uses up slightly more energy when it is turned black (all liquid crystals polarised under the voltage and obscuring the backlight) than when it is bright (only backlight is on, liquid crystals not polarised).